# Add trusted CA to Debian/Ubuntu image

Tags: ssl, docker, debian

I'm trying to deploy a CA certificate as a trusted root certificate in a Debian/nodejs container as described in https://askubuntu.com/a/94861/88763 or http://blog.bigon.be/2014/03/22/add-a-new-ca-certificate-to-the-certificates-stash-in-debian/ but it fails with no apparent reason. My Dockerfile:

```
FROM debian:jessie # or buildpack-deps:jessie or node:5
RUN apt-get update -y && \
    apt-get install ca-certificates netcat strace wget -y
ADD rootCa.pem /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/rootCa.crt
RUN update-ca-certificates --verbose

CMD ["netcat", "-l", "12345"] # just to keep the container running
```

When building the container it actually tells me a certificate was added (`1 added, 0 removed; done.`) Nonetheless, when I try to use the root CA with wget, it is not found:

```
$ sudo docker exec -it cleanslatehg_catests_1 wget https://foo.v3.testing
converted 'https://foo.v3.testing' (ANSI_X3.4-1968) -> 'https://foo.v3.testing' (UTF-8)
--2016-02-02 15:11:33--  https://foo.v3.testing/
Resolving foo.v3.testing (foo.v3.testing)... 172.19.0.7
Connecting to foo.v3.testing (foo.v3.testing)|172.19.0.7|:443... connected.
ERROR: The certificate of 'foo.v3.testing' is not trusted.
```

Using the Ubuntu base image, I can access https://foo.v3.testing successfully:

```
FROM ubuntu
RUN apt-get update -y && \
    apt-get install ca-certificates netcat strace wget -y
ADD rootCa.pem /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/rootCa.crt
RUN update-ca-certificates --verbose

CMD ["netcat", "-l", "12345"]

$ sudo docker exec -it cleanslatehg_catests_1 wget https://foo.v3.testing
--2016-02-02 15:23:17--  https://foo.v3.testing/
Resolving foo.v3.testing (foo.v3.testing)... 172.19.0.7
Connecting to foo.v3.testing (foo.v3.testing)|172.19.0.7|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
[…]
2016-02-02 15:23:17 (33.9 MB/s) - 'index.html' saved [170/170]
```

Comment: I think your problem is the format of the certificate. See https://superuser.com/questions/437330/how-do-you-add-a-certificate-authority-ca-to-ubuntu